# How to play a video without using plugin?

Tags: videos

I want to play a video inside my site itself without using any plugins.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you identify what type of video? Are you talking about hosted videos on third-party services or self-hosted videos you upload into WP yourself?

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible. You can use [oEmbed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds) for some video sources, but for your own video you have to decide what a player you want to use.

That’s exactly what plugins are for. There is no point in avoiding using them.

*Update*

In WordPress 3.6 support for native audio and video was added. Use the shortcodes `[audio src="your/url"]` and `[video src="your/url"]` to embed these files and get proper players.

Comment: Another question Does wordpress supports html5 fully?

Comment: Your theme has to do that. WordPress serves the data, the theme creates the output.

Comment: sorry to disturb you, I want to know the plugin name that should search the contents present inside the pdf files or .doc files or any txt files ? is there any plugin like that?

Comment: 1. I don’t know. 2. Please do not ask new questions in comments. 3. Plugin recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/73) now, sorry.